# Do I need to worry about thread safety if I am only reading from a collection?

Tags: java, concurrency

I want to pass a pre-built Map to multiple threads that are going to only read the values from the Map simultaneously. Do I need to worry about concurrent access and use the ConcurrentHashMap instead of HashMap in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You still need to make sure that there is a "happens-before" relationship between the thread that creates and initializes the Map, and the threads that subsequently read it.  If there is no such relationship, it is *theoretically possible* for the reading threads to see stale data.

If you create and populate the Map in the thread that starts the other threads ... before it does this ... you should be fine.

Another simple way to ensure safety is to do something like this:

```
public class Foo {
    private final Map map;

    public Foo(....) {
        map = new HashMap();
        // populate
    }

    public Map getMap() {
        // If the 'map' is final, and nothing changes it apart from 
        // the constructor, this method doesn't need to be synchronized.
    }
```

Both of these will result in a "happens-before" relationship between the creation / initialization, and each thread's first use of the Map.

You could also declare `map` in the above to be `volatile`, but is likely to cause more cache flushes than strictly need to occur; i.e. you'll take a small performance hit.

Comment: Depending on the exact situation, `volatile` may not be avoidable, but, as you note, should be avoided if the situation permits.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - you are correct.  However, I was assuming that *"I want to pass a **pre-built** Map to multiple threads"* means that the Map is built before the threads are started.  (Construing it any other way would be stretching the English language ...)

Comment: This is the sense for me: "I want to publish to other threads an instance of Map that I have fully constructed before the action of publishing".

Answer (score 3):

What you could do, additionally, in order to ensure that will be handled just for reading operations is to give back an [Collections.unmodifiableMap(Map)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap%28java.util.Map%29).

Answer (score 2):

In theory, concurrent reading should not cause problems on collections.

However if you modify it even once, it is prone to error, and then you should use a concurrent version.

Comment: Even without modification there will be a problem if there is no `happens-before` relationship between reads and the initial writes.

Comment: Yes, it is a clear requirement, that the initial values must be present before passing the Hash to use by other threads.

Comment: They won't be present if special care hasn't been taken to ensure the existence of the `happens-before` relationship. This is a term defined by the JLS.

Answer (score 2):

It is safe to pass the HashMap if all the threads are reading it. However, before passing the map I would call  Collections.unmodifiableMap() to make sure that if one of thread accidentally modified it because some programmer in the future did not respect the current contract you will get an exception.

Comment: `unmodifiableMap` call will do nothing to ensure that the map is properly published to other threads. There will be no `happens-before` ordering imposed.

Comment: Marko the question says the Map is preBuilt if you make it unmodifiable and pass the unmodifiable map in how can the threads modify the map?

Comment: It is pre-built only inside the thread that created it. You don't seem to be familiar with the Java memory model and the `happen-before` relationship.

Comment: Marko you are correct, I did not understand the Java Memory Model I am quite surprised about its implications.

Answer (score 2):

You always need to worry about thread safety. In your specific example, it will be enough if you

1. fully construct the map in a single thread;
2. publish it to other threads by setting a `volatile` variable to refer to it.

Or, if that is an option, make sure the threads are not started until the map is ready.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, You dont have to worry about it.
Unless until someone going to change pre-built map while thread are accessing it.

Answer (score 1):

No you dont need to use it. Conflicts are generated only in following cases:

- When some threads may read the data, while others may try to overwrite it.
- The second is when every thread tries to update the data.

When each thread is only trying to read the values, no conflicts are generated.

Comment: A lot of people have answered along the same lines as you, and they are all wrong. You are ignoring the implications of the Java memory model. Specifically, without imposing a proper `happens-before` relationship between the writes and reads, there is no guarantee of thread safety.

Comment: True enough. But their are no relationships between reads and writes as the question says clearly that all the threads only _read_ the values.

Comment: They won't be reading the proper values in the absence of a `happens-before` relationship between the last write and any read. Your answer doesn't specify how to impose that relationship.